# Want to Get the Index Number of the Array

Tags: matlab

I have one row with 10 columns like

[.02 .024 .035 .046 .056 .25 .05 .045 0.36 0.01]

I want to know the column number of this array where the sum of the row elements will be equal to 0.42 or the closest one of 0.42. Like in this case the sum up to the 6th column is 0.431 which is not equal to 0.42 but closest to it, so my answer is 6th column. But how get the column number in MatLab?

Need help from MatLab experts.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following lines:

```
a = [.02 .024 .035 .046 .056 .25 .05 .045 0.36 0.01]
b = cumsum(a)
c = abs(b-0.42)
d = find(c == min(c))
```

You can contract them in a one-liner if you want.

Comment: [~,d] = min(abs(cumsum(a)-0.42))